# How to discriminate unions of string literal types?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement a declarative API for writing CSS styles using MDN metadata and TypeScript. My goal is to cast generic string values to string literal types so I can user it later on, either code-generating "const" files from json metadata or dynamically.

```
const data = [
  { type: 'at-rule', value: '@media' },
  { type: 'css-property', value: 'color' }
]

const createPrefix = <P extends string>(prefix: P) => <A extends string>(it: A) => `${prefix}: ${it};` as `${P}: ${A}`

const color = createPrefix('color') // works

// usage
const blueText = color('blue')
// const blueText: 'color: blue;'
```

###### Usage

Ideally we'd generate string literals similar (in format) to the value of `cssText` property of a `CSSStyleRule`.

```
import * as s from './composers'

s.of('button-primary').color('blue').background('white')
// .button-primary { color: blue; background: white; }
```

I've been struggling for a whole week with this. Probably because I don't understand TypeScript well enough. Regardless, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
type AtRule =
  | '@color-profile'
  | '@charset'
  | '@counter-style'
  | '@document'
  | '@font-face'
  | '@font-feature-values'
  | '@import'
  | '@property'
  | '@keyframes'
  | '@viewport'
  | '@media'
  | '@namespace'
  | '@page'
  | '@supports'

const createPrefix =
  <A extends AtRule>(a: A) =>
  <B extends string>(b: B) => {
    return `${a}: ${b};` as const
  }

function getComposer<T extends AtRule>(s: T) {
  const value: T = s
  return createPrefix(value)
}

const data = [{ value: '@charset' }, { value: '@document' }] as const

const prefixes = data.map(d => getComposer(d.value))

const something = prefixes[0]('blue')
console.log(something) // → '@charset: blue;'
// const something: "@charset: blue;" | "@document: blue;"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You didn't describe what it is that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, updated now.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NByozw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, you're an absolute legend. I've read many of your articles and answers in the past, and I'm an invisible admirer of you (ts-knowledge wise). Thank you. That does meet my needs! Should I remove the question as it seems to be a duplicate of the the approach you've pasted here?

Comment: The already posted answer is quite similar so I think I'll leave this alone unless something about it doesn't work for you.  EDIT: my link was to a playground example I made in response to this question; it's not some existing thing that your question duplicates.

Comment: Got it. I guess my examples set the wrong path. I was trying to avoid having to declare an interface for each `{ type: 'at-rule', value: '@media' }` chunk of metadata as it seemed very repetitive. I'll try to leverage `quicktype` to cast the metadata or use `csstype` types to derive composers. Leaving the question as it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go through generics:

```js
  const createPrefix = <A extends string>(a: A) => <B extends string>(b: B) => {
    return `${a}:${b}` as `${A}:${B}`
  }
  function getComposer<T extends Prop>(s: T) {
    switch (s.value) {
      case "background":
        return createPrefix<T['value']>(s.value)
      case "color":
        return createPrefix<T['value']>(s.value)
      default:
        return assertNever(s);
    }
  }
```

Comment: or you can go with just `function getComposer<T extends Prop>(s: T) { return createPrefix<T['value']>(s.value) }`

Comment: Note that `\`${a}:${b}\` as const` will also have the type `\`${A}:${B}\``

Comment: yes this should be safer